# Ionic Dark Mode - Force Light/Dark and System theme

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I would like to add a toggle for my Ionic project that controls the theme of the entire application. The toggle can force a light mode/dark mode irrespective of what the system mode is (ie. stays dark mode even if the system turns from dark -> light) and also an option to toggle back to automatic.

Currently what I have done is follow the Ionic Conference App https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app and what I've done to my base project is:

1. Remove `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` from `variables.scss` and add `.dark-theme` class to the media queries, ie. `body` -> `.dark-theme`, `.ios body` -> `.dark-theme.ios`
2. Add an `ion-segment` to my settings page:

```
    <ion-label position="fixed">Mode</ion-label>
    <ion-segment
      [(ngModel)]="modeService.mode"
      (ionChange)="modeService.setMode()"
    >
      <ion-segment-button value="light">
        <ion-label>Light</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="dark">
        <ion-label>Dark</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="auto">
        <ion-label>Auto</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
```

3. in my `modeService.ts` file (which is the service I use to save the mode to the storage and handle the mode change:

```
dark: boolean;
  mode = 'auto';
  prefDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  constructor() { }

  setMode = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const storeMode = this.mode;

    await Storage.set({
      key: 'mode',
      value: storeMode
    });

    if (this.mode !== 'auto') {
      this.dark = (this.mode === 'dark') ? true : false;
    } else {
      this.dark = this.prefDark.matches;
      this.prefDark.addEventListener('change', e => {
        this.dark = e.matches;
      });
    }
  };

  checkMode = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const { value } = await Storage.get({ key: 'mode' });
    if (value) {
      this.mode = value;
    }
  };
}
```

4. In `app.component.html` I added `[class.dark-theme]="modeService.dark"` to `<ion-app>`
5. In `app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  prefDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  constructor(
    private themeService: ThemesService,
    public teamService: TeamService,
    private helpService: HelpService,
    public modeService: ModeService,
    private router: Router,
    public modalController: ModalController,
    private menuController: MenuController,
  ) { }

 async ngOnInit() {
    await ... /// some other theme change
    if (this.modeService.mode === 'auto') {
      this.modeService.dark = this.prefDark.matches;
      this.prefDark.addEventListener('change', e => {
        this.modeService.dark = e.matches;
      });
    }
  }
```

The problem is, the toggle work but say when I have the segment to `dark` and the OS theme is changed to `dark`, then I toggle the OS theme to `light` the app turns back to the light theme and does not keep the dark theme.

Answer (score 2):

I remade your question in my own project. There are a few changes that I made, most notably to the `modeService.ts`. (I changed the name to ColorModeService)

Below are the code snippits from the relevant files.

```js
// color-mode.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export type ColorMode = 'auto' | 'dark' | 'light';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ColorModeService {
  /**
   * Variable that controls the user interface. Used to toggle 'dark-theme' class.
   */
  public darkMode$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  // Check user preference for light/dark theme
  private prefDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  constructor() {
    // Set user preferred mode on refresh.
    this.setMode(this.getMode());

    // Change between light/dark theme based on device settings
    if (this.getMode() === 'auto') {
      this.darkMode$.next(this.prefDark.matches);
      this.listenToColorModeChanges();
    }
  }

  private applyColorModeChanges = (event: any) => {
    this.darkMode$.next(event.matches);
  }

  private listenToColorModeChanges() {
    this.prefDark.addEventListener('change', this.applyColorModeChanges);
  }

  private removeColorModeChangesListener() {
    this.prefDark.removeEventListener('change', this.applyColorModeChanges);
  }

  /**
   * Set user preferred color mode.
   */
  setMode = (colorMode: ColorMode) => {
    localStorage.setItem('mode', colorMode);

    switch (colorMode) {
      case 'auto':
        this.darkMode$.next(this.prefDark.matches);
        this.listenToColorModeChanges();
        break;

      case 'dark':
        this.darkMode$.next(true);
        this.removeColorModeChangesListener();
        break;

      case 'light':
        this.darkMode$.next(false);
        this.removeColorModeChangesListener();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  /**
   * Get user preferred color mode.
   */
  getMode = (): ColorMode => {
    // Get user preferred mode from localStorage and if not set return default
    return localStorage.getItem('mode') as ColorMode ?? 'auto';
  }
}
```

```js
// app.component.ts

import { ColorModeService } from 'src/app/services/color-mode.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    colorMode: ColorModeService
  ) {
    colorMode.darkMode$.subscribe((darkMode) => {
      if (darkMode) {
        document.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
      } else {
        document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- settings.component.html -->

<ion-item-group>
  <ion-item-divider>
    <ion-label>Thema</ion-label>
  </ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
      Choose a theme for the app below. Auto follows your device settings.
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item class="color-mode-toggle">
    <ion-segment (ionChange)="changeColorScheme($event)" value="{{currentColorMode}}">
      <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let colorMode of colorModes" value="{{colorMode}}">
        <ion-label>{{colorMode}}</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
```

```js
// settings.component.ts

public colorModes: ColorMode[] = ['auto', 'dark', 'light'];

constructor(
  private colorMode: ColorModeService
  ) { }

async changeColorScheme(event: any) {
  const colorMode = event.detail.value;
  this.colorMode.setMode(colorMode);
}
```

---

Sidenote: to get this to work on Android devices, you'll need to change:

`<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

in `android/app/main/red/values/styles.xml`

to `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">`.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and cannot get your solution to work. Can you show what changes would be required in the other files?

Comment: If I remove `this.prefDark.addEventListener` then your solution works but the problem with this is, auto will not be updated when OS theme is changed unless you refresh the page--this is not ideal.

Comment: @iamthestreets I updated the examples above to include all the relevant files. The ColorModeService component was also updated in the meanwhile, so I updated that file as well. The current solution listens to OS theme changes, so maybe the code I shared had a bug.